# Jquery function executed on page load instead on the .click() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've this code from a javascript file of mine, this should display the result of a search in an XML file when clicking an image tagged "White"; the problem is that the function is executed on page load, not when the image is clicked...
Any help?
HTML code of the image:

```
<img src="images/White.png" id="White">
```

And there is the javascript code:

```
function genericSearch(xml, tipo) {
    $(xml).find("mazzo").each(function() {
        var nome = $(this).find("nome").text();
        var color = $(this).find("colori").text();
        if (color.match(tipo)){
            $("ol#lista").append("<li>"+$(this).find("nome").text()+"   "+color+"</li>");}
     });
}

function specificSearch(){
    var white = document.getElementById("White");
    white.click(function(){
        genericSearch(nodo, "White");
    });
}
```

A last comment, "tipo" is just a parameter passed when calling the genericSearch function, while nodo is just a previously declared variable, code:

```
var nodo = parseXML("xml/file.xml");
```

Comment: What do you mean 'tagged' White.  <White/>?

Comment: Is `tipo` a regular expression? How are you calling the function ?

Comment: My shower doesn't work. Can you explain why with no other information?

Comment: @CarlMarkham - Sure, you didn't pay your water bill !

Comment: Edited, sorry for being vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call `genericSearch` on event click, you need to set the behaviour on ready event:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#White').click(function(){
        genericSearch(nodo, "White");
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe, it doesn't work because there are some errors. You can try to write a message on console (Chrome - F12 - Console tab). For example:

$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#White').click(function(){
        console.log("click!");
        genericSearch(nodo, "White");
    });
});

Comment: you where right, nodo was declared in the wrong place, LOL
thank you very much ^_^